# Validating queryparam values jersey

Tags: jaxb, jersey, jax-rs, wadl

Are there any other ways besides the one below to validate query parameter values i.e. is there a Jersey way to this by mapping to a schema via a wadl. Thank you

```
@Path("smooth")
@GET
public Response smooth(
    @DefaultValue("blue") @QueryParam("min-color") ColorParam minColor,

public class ColorParam extends Color {
 public ColorParam(String s) {
    super(getRGB(s));
 }

 private static int getRGB(String s) {
    if (s.charAt(0) == '#') {
        try {
            Color c = Color.decode("0x" + s.substring(1));
            return c.getRGB();
        } catch (NumberFormatException e) {
            throw new WebApplicationException(400);
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Unfortunately, there is limited support for validation on current JAX-RS version. But according to the [draft for JAX-RS 2.0](http://java.net/projects/jax-rs-spec), it will have much better validation handling in the future.

You can see an example of the new features [here](http://java.net/projects/jax-rs-spec/pages/Validation).